# How can I find the longest and shortest line in a text file?

Tags: java

I am writing a program that uses the Scanner method to read a text file and outputs: the number of words, Number of sentences, Average number of words per sentence, The longest sentence and shortest sentence. So far I have everything but the longest and shortest sentences and I can't seem to figure them out. Here's what I have so far...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
public class TestScanner {
  public static void main(String args[])
  {     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String x = in.next();
        double count=0;
        int nbSentences = 0;
        while(in.hasNext())
        {   String word = in.next();
            nbSentences +=getNbSentences(word);
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Number of Words: "+ count);
        System.out.println("Number of Sentences: " + nbSentences);
        System.out.println("Average Words In Sentence: " + (count/nbSentences));
        System.out.println("Longest Sentence: ");
        System.out.println("Shortest Sentence: ");
 }
 //**************************number of sentences*********************************
 public static int getNbSentences(String word) 
 {         int result = 0;
       char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
       for(Character c : chars) 
       {    if(c == '.' || c == '!' || c == '?') 
            {   result++; 
            }
       }
       return result;
 }
 //*************************Longest Sentence*************************************


 //This is where I'm stuck....

}
```

If anyone could help I would HIGHLY appreciate it!!

Comment: You're attempting the count the number of sentences *within a token* (i.e. word). Clearly, a sentence is likely to span more than one token. Indeed, some can span multiple lines.

Comment: Try ouy this URL :http://www.unc.edu/~sunnyliu/inls161/FileProcessor.java

They have some info on how to do it. Search for longest sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Pseodo code:

1. Set first sentence as longest and shortest.
2. Iterate over all sentences, compare them to the shortest and longest.
3. If you find a shorter sentence than shortest, use it as shortest.
4. If you find a longer sentence than longest, use it as longest.

Comment: Yes, but how do I do this is what I am trying to figure out. I don't understand how to get the program to read the input as words(not lines), figure out the beginnings and ends of sentences, then figure out which one is the longest and which one is the shortest.

Answer (score 1):

1. Initialize `int currentSentenceLength = 0` and `int maxSentenceLength = 0` outside of your loop.
2. For each `word`: increment `currentSentenceLength`.
3. If `word` contains `.`, `!` or `?` do : `maxSentenceLength = Math.max(currentSentenceLength, maxSentenceLength); currentSentenceLength = 0;`
4. return `maxSentenceLength`

You can do the same thing for the shortest sentence.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do, but I don't really understand how to code it.

Answer (score 1):

The below code finds the longest and smallest line along with line number from text file.(Limitation: if two lines are same then it considers first one as long or short line).
I have used HashMap for storing line(line number as key and line content as value)

If anything need to be add to this code please post.

`          package test;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class LongestAndShortestLineFinder {

static int previousLongLine = 0;
static int previousShortLine = 10000;

public void printLongLine(HashMap longLineMap) {

    Set keyofSet = longLineMap.keySet();
    Iterator itr = keyofSet.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Integer keys = (Integer) itr.next();
        String value = (String) longLineMap.get(keys);
        System.out.println("Line Number of Longest line: " + keys
                + "\nLongest line: " + value);
    }
}

public void printShortLine(HashMap shortLineMap) {

    Set keyofSet = shortLineMap.keySet();
    Iterator itr = keyofSet.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Integer keys = (Integer) itr.next();
        String value = (String) shortLineMap.get(keys);

        System.out.println("Line Number of Shortest line: " + keys
                + "\nShortest line: " + value);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String fileName = "d:\\test.txt";
    // This will reference one line at a time
    String line = null;
    int key = 0;
    int lineSize = 0, lineNumber = 0;

    LongestAndShortestLineFinder ln = new LongestAndShortestLineFinder();

    HashMap longLineMap = new HashMap();
    HashMap shortLineMap = new HashMap();

    try {
        // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            lineNumber++;
            lineSize = line.length();
            if (lineSize > previousLongLine) {
                previousLongLine = lineSize;
                longLineMap.clear();
                longLineMap.put(lineNumber, line);
            }
            if (lineSize < previousShortLine) {
                previousShortLine = lineSize;
                shortLineMap.clear();
                shortLineMap.put(lineNumber, line);
            }

        }
        // Always close files.
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");
        // Or we could just do this:
        // ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    ln.printLongLine(longLineMap);
    ln.printShortLine(shortLineMap);
}

 }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

According to your source code, what you would need to do is to obtain the number of words in a sentence. Then you can either update variables which would store the current min/max number of words in a sentence store or sotre the number of words in sentences as a collection and obtain the max, min (and eventually the average) a posteriori.

Explicitly: change the corresponding lines in the `main` method to

```
double count = 0;
int nbSentences = 0;
int nbWordsInASentence = 0;
Collection nbWordsInSentences = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (in.hasNext())
{   String word = in.next();
    count++;
    nbWordsInASentence++;

    int incrementNbSentences = getNbSentences(word);
    if (incrementNbSentences > 0) {
        nbWordsInASentence.add(nbWordsInASentence);
        nbWordsInASentence = 0;
    }
}

int maxSentenceLength;
int minSentenceLength;
if (nbWordsInSentences.size() > 0)
{   maxSentenceLength = Collections.max(nbWordsInSentences);
    minSentenceLength = Collections.min(nbWordsInSentences);
}
else
{   maxSentenceLength = 0; // use whatever value seems appropriate
    minSentenceLength = 0; // use whatever value seems appropriate
}
```

But this only works if the result from `getNbSentences` is never larger than 1 (which would be implied by the fact that the input argument is a word).

Please note that the implementation of the method `getNbSentences` the hypothesis might not be true in the case of suspension marks: the method returns 3 in this occurrence.